Okta Usernames | Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
I am trying to pull a list of okta usernames through a csv file of user's emails but I keep getting an invoke-restmethod error.
$apiToken = "api"
$oktaDomain = "domain.okta"
# get okta username by email
function Get-OktaUsernameByEmail {
   param (
       [string]$email
   )
   $headers = @{
       "Authorization" = "SSWS $apiToken"
       "Content-Type"        = "application/json"
   }
   $url = "https://$oktaDomain/api/v1/users?q=$email"
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get
   if ($response) {
       return $response[0].profile.login
   } else {
       return $null
   }
}
# path for input
$inputcsvPath = "path\input.csv"
# path for output
$outputcsvPath = "path\output.csv"
# read input
$emails = Import-Csv -Path $inputCsvPath
# store results
$results = @()
foreach ($email in $emails) {
   $userEmail = $email.Email
   $username = Get-OktaUsernameByEmail -email $userEmail
   $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
       Email    = $userEmail
       Username = $username
   }
}
# export csv file
$results | export-csv -Path $outputcsvPath -NoTypeInformation`

#ERROR
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:15 char:16

... $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get ...

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand




You do not have the credentials to access the route "api/v1/users".
